# Binary modulo operation

Tags: math, modulo

My apologies, this question is now redirected to

[this web page in math forum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2535220/binary-modulo-operation).

<strike>Empirically, I can know that (a+b+c) mod 2 = (a-b-c) mod 2.</strike>

> e.g.,)
>
> 1+2+3 = 6, 6 mod 2 = 0
> 1-2-3 = -4, -4 mod 2 = 0
>
> 1+2+4 = 7, 7 mod 2 = 1
> 1-2-4 = -5, -5 mod 2 = 1

It seems that it is only possible when we use binary modulo (mod 2).

Is there any formal proof for this?

Comment: It's also possible for a modulus of one.

Comment: This is math problem rather than a programming problem. It belongs on [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: adding `a` to each side of the equality adds no additional information, and by a change of variable t=a+b the statement simply becomes "prove that if t=-t mod n for all integers t then n=2". In particular, that implies that 2=k*n, and since 2 is a prime we have k=1 and n=2.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: I am so sorry I couldn't help but notice some math problems were posted on this web-site and I thought that it would be allowed to upload this question. I asked the same question at the math forum -> 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2535220/binary-modulo-operation

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, why this ended up on SO. As James said in the comments, these questions should be asked on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) But since it is here:

I a + b + c = a - b - c + 2(b + c)

II 2(b + c)  ≡  0 (mod 2), ergo

III a + b + c  ≡  a - b - c (mod 2)

Edit, since it was requested: The generalisation of II would require n to be a divisor of 2 to fulfill

2(b + c)  ≡  0 (mod n)

for all b and c, which means that n is either 1 or 2.

Comment: That doesn't prove that it's only possible for a modulus of two.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this works `mod 2` is exactly because there are only two residues: 0 and 1. And thus it is true that for any `x`

`x ≡ -x mod 2`

Thus `a + b ≡ a - b mod 2`

Obviously this is not true for any other modulo operation. So for any other `n > 2` you can create a simple counter-example for `(a+b+c) ≡ (a-b-c) mod n`:

1. a = n
2. b = 0
3. c = 1

`(a + b + c) mod n` = `1`

`(a - b - c) mod n` = `n - 1`

Obviously `n - 1` is not equal to `1` if `n > 2`. Actually most of the triplets (`a`, `b`, `c`) would be counter-examples for any `n > 2`.